# Calculating a confidence interval for a weighted sample

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, descriptive-statistics, weighted-data

In a nutshell, I'd like to compute a confidence interval for some weighted sample data where the final value I'm seeking is a sum of different weighted samples. Illustrated here with a toy example set of observations:

```
item | value | weight
A    | 1.5   | 0.33
A    | 2.1   | 0.67
B    | 6.7   | 0.5
B    | 5.0   | 0.5
```

The value I am interested in is (A + B). The sample mean is easy enough here: I just sum the weighted average of observed A with the weighted average of observed B.

My question is how to calculate a confidence interval around this sample mean (A + B). If I was ONLY interested in A, I think I'd utilize the Student's T distribution along with a weighted standard error calculated as described [here](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman2/ch2/weightsd.pdf).

I'm struggling to understand how I would propagate that to the sum (A + B), though. Any suggestions? Perhaps I'm overthinking the whole thing already?

Any input appreciated.

Comment: If you can assume that your observations are independent (and that the weight you attach to them is fixed, and in particular not a random variable that is correlated with the observation itself), you can obtain an estimate by first calculating estimated variances for A and B as $\widehat{V}_A$ and $\widehat{V}_B$, and in a second step by taking the sum $\sum_{i=1}w_i^2\text{Var}({V_{c_i}})$, where $c_i$ is either A or B and gives the *class label* of $i$. But as I said, you need independence of observations for this.

Comment: The apt comment by @Jeremias implicitly asks you to edit your post to include explanations of what your weights mean, how you go about measuring or computing them, and how they might or might not be related to the data.  These things are important to know before recommending any confidence interval procedure.

Comment: suppose the weights are correlated with the observation, because the weights are chosen such that the sample means correspond with population means, what would be an appropriate procedure for obtaining confidence intervals?